# How to take ownership of a PPA?

Tags: ppa, launchpad

Say there's a software that wasn't created for Ubuntu but someone creatred a PPA for it and I use that PPA.

Now the PPA owner, doesn't want to maintain the PPA anymore. Can I ask the owner to hand it over, so that I maintain the ppa? If so how? And what does maintaining the PPA require besides updating the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your question is very broad, but I will try to give some guidance.

Contact the current ppa owner and coordinate your efforts. You can skin the cat more then one way, probably easiest to make a work group that maintains the ppa. Perhaps the old maintainer can (briefly) mentor you.

https://help.launchpad.net/Teams/CreatingAndRunning

If you do not know how to package, I highly suggest you read the packaging guidelines. http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/

Launchpad / a ppa greatly automates much of the process, but nothing replaces at least a working knowledge of packaging, especially if you hope one day to have your package in the Debian / Ubuntu repositories.

On the flip side, improper packaging often causes problems / compatibility problems.

Next read the ppa tutorial - https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA